# chaco - making several Containers show separate plots

Tags: traits, traitsui, chaco

I have written a chaco plotting class that plots some data and allows the user to interact with it. I then wanted to make a TraitsUI GUI that has several different instances of this chaco plot so that the user can have several of the plots and interact with them independently.

However, when I try and implement this I seem to get that each of the separate instances of my chaco plot are displaying all the data from all the plots. I have made a very simple GUI below that reproduces the problem.

In the example below I would like each tab to show a container with a single line plot. However, each container seems to plot all the plots that have been plotted in any of the containers. From the documentation here [chaco container docs](http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/containers.html#overlay-plot-container), I think what I have done should work.

I have also tried using the ListEditor view, but this has the same problem.

Am I misunderstanding something about chaco Containers? How can I get each container instance to act independently? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
import enthought.chaco.api as chaco
import enthought.traits.api as traits
import enthought.traits.ui.api as traitsui
from enthought.enable.api import  ComponentEditor
import scipy


class BasicPlot(traits.HasTraits):

    container = chaco.Plot(padding=(120,20,20,40), bgcolor="white",
                                     use_backbuffer = True,
                                     border_visible = True,
                                     fill_padding = True)



    traits_view = traitsui.View(traitsui.Item('container', editor = ComponentEditor(), show_label = False),
                       width = 500, height = 500,
                       resizable = True, title = "My line plot")

    def __init__(self, n, *args, **kw):
        super(BasicPlot, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        xs = scipy.linspace(0, 6.3, 1000)
        ys = scipy.sin(n*xs)
        plot = chaco.create_line_plot([xs,ys])
        self.container.add(plot)
        chaco.add_default_grids(plot)
        chaco.add_default_axes(plot)

class tabbedPlots(traits.HasTraits):

    bp1 = BasicPlot(1)
    bp2 = BasicPlot(2)

    bpGroup = traitsui.Group(traitsui.Item("bp1", editor = traitsui.InstanceEditor(), style="custom", show_label=False),
                              traitsui.Item("bp2", editor = traitsui.InstanceEditor(), style="custom", show_label=False), layout="tabbed")

    traits_view = traitsui.View(bpGroup,title = "Log File Plots")    


class tabbedPlotsList(traits.HasTraits):

    bps = traits.List(BasicPlot)


    bpGroup = traitsui.Group(
                        traitsui.Item('bps',style="custom",
                                      editor=traitsui.ListEditor(use_notebook=True, deletable=True,export = 'DockWindowShell', page_name=".name")
                                      ,label="logFilePlots", show_label=False)
                                      )

    traits_view = traitsui.View(bpGroup,title = "Log File Plots")

    def __init__(self, **traitsDict):
       super(tabbedPlotsList, **traitsDict)
       self.bps = [BasicPlot(n) for n in range(0,8)]

if __name__=="__main__":

    gui = tabbedPlots()
    gui.configure_traits()
    gui2 = tabbedPlotsList()
    gui2.configure_traits()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to this.

```
def __init__(self, n, *args, **kw):
    super(BasicPlot, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    self.container = chaco.Plot(padding=(120,20,20,40), bgcolor="white",
                                     use_backbuffer = True,
                                     border_visible = True,
                                     fill_padding = True)
    xs = scipy.linspace(0, 6.3, 1000)
    ys = scipy.sin(n*xs)
    plot = chaco.create_line_plot([xs,ys])
    self.container.add(plot)
    chaco.add_default_grids(plot)
    chaco.add_default_axes(plot)
```

To make it work as desired the container cannot be a class attribute. Instead it must be defined inside the **init** as self.container(...). (This makes sense)

If this change is made you get the desired functionality.